# Is there a way using Ruby to login to a remote windows server and then restart services?

Tags: ruby

Ruby is sitting on a Windows machine for debugging, but will move it to a Linux machine later.

Now I would like to write a ruby script that can login to a remote Windows server and then restart Windows Services.

Is there anything like Net/SSH that I can use to do this with Windows machines?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the net-ssh gem it could be accomplished.

http://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh